# Как извлечь информацию из ячейки переменной и поместить ее в дублированную строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть набор данных с колонкой "`UserID`", '`System`' - система которая используется пользователем и конкатенацией этих двух колонок. Вот пример [данных](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvyynzjr9a22908/RolCatBR_IDMqes1.xlsx?dl=0):

```
>>RolCatBR_IDMqes1.loc[0:11]

     UserID            System         CONCAT A
0   ANTANAS  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|ANTANAS
1   AWYGASC  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|AWYGASC
2   CHENQIA  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|CHENQIA
3   CHENQIA  P3Z_020, P3Z_030  P3Z_020|CHENQIA
4   DBORZUT  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|DBORZUT
5   DURAKER  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|DURAKER
6   JEBINDE  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|JEBINDE
7   SMETTAN  P1B_010, P2Z_010  P1B_010|SMETTAN
8   TKAUL13  P3Z_020, P3Z_030  P3Z_020|TKAUL13
9   VATERCH  P3Z_020, P3Z_030  P3Z_020|VATERCH
10  ABUNNEN           P2Z_010  P2Z_010|ABUNNEN
11  AMILSKI           P2Z_010  P2Z_010|AMILSKI
```

Например: первая строка `[0]`, мне нужно вытвщить данные о системе - `P2Z_010`, создать новую строку с тем же `UserID` и поставить системную информацию - `P2Z_010` с обновленным `CONCAT A`.

Чтобы получилось:

```
       UserID   System           CONCAT A
0     ANTANAS  P1B_010    P1B_010|ANTANAS
0.5   ANTANAS  P2Z_010    P2Z_010|ANTANAS
1     AWYGASC  P1B_010    P1B_010|AWYGASC
1.5   AWYGASC  P2Z_010    P2Z_010|AWYGASC
...
```

Я попробовал применить способ который предложил @Wen:

```
s2 = RolCatBR_IDMqes1['System'].str.split(',')
w2 = pd.DataFrame({
       'UserID':RolCatBR_IDMqes1['UserID'].repeat(s2.str.len().fillna(value=0).astype(int)),
       'System':sum(s2.tolist(),[]),
       'CONCATA':RolCatBR_IDMqes1['CONCATA'].repeat(s2.str.len().fillna(value=0).astype(int))
     })
```

Но у меня возникает ошибка и я не знаю как её исправить:

```
File "<ipython-input-93-42d2e6fcce42>", line 1, in <module>
    sum(s2.tolist(),[])

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list
```

Как мне извлечь информацию из ячейки переменной и поместить ее в дублированную строку? Или исправить ошибку чтобы способ сработал?

Пример данных для воспроизводства ошибки:

> `df1 = df.iloc[1130:1140]
>   df1
>   Out[79]: 
>       UserID   System         CONCAT A
>   1130      NaN      NaN              NaN
>   1131  AYNERDO  P1B_010  P1B_010|AYNERDO
>   1132  CKIESCH  P1B_010  P1B_010|CKIESCH
>   1133  JBRETTS  P1B_010  P1B_010|JBRETTS
>   1134  YASSMAN  P1B_010  P1B_010|YASSMAN
>   1135  EPFITZE  P1B_010  P1B_010|EPFITZE
>   1136      NaN      NaN              NaN
>   1137  HUBBARA  P1B_010  P1B_010|HUBBARA
>   1138  TQUINTO  P1B_010  P1B_010|TQUINTO
>   1139      NaN      NaN              NaN`

`list(df1)
Out[80]: ['UserID', 'System', 'CONCAT A']`

Потом я задаю функцию в систему. 
А затем исполняю код
`res = explode(df.assign(System=df['System'].str.split(',\s*',                                                   expand=False)), ['System'])`

`line 42, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)`

`TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') according to the rule 'safe'`

Мне кажется я понял почему так происходит, возможно дело в NaN. Сейчас попробую их заменить на ноль, или убрать лучше?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [самописной функцией `explode()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12680754/split-explode-pandas-dataframe-string-entry-to-separate-rows/40449726#40449726):

```
In [283]: res = explode(df.assign(System=df['System'].str.split(',\s*', 
                                                                expand=False)), 
                        ['System'])

In [284]: res
Out[284]:
         UserID   System          CONCAT A
0       ANTANAS  P1B_010   P1B_010|ANTANAS
1       ANTANAS  P2Z_010   P1B_010|ANTANAS
2       AWYGASC  P1B_010   P1B_010|AWYGASC
3       AWYGASC  P2Z_010   P1B_010|AWYGASC
4       CHENQIA  P1B_010   P1B_010|CHENQIA
5       CHENQIA  P2Z_010   P1B_010|CHENQIA
6       CHENQIA  P3Z_020   P3Z_020|CHENQIA
...         ...      ...               ...
14868    RKLESS  P1B_010    P1B_010|RKLESS
14869   SARACHR  P1B_010   P1B_010|SARACHR
14870   TGUNZEN  P1B_010   P1B_010|TGUNZEN
14871  TSCHULTK  P1B_010  P1B_010|TSCHULTK
14872    WEHEIL  P1B_010    P1B_010|WEHEIL
14873   RSIELAF  P1B_010   P1B_010|RSIELAF
14874   SCHUESA  P3Z_020   P3Z_020|SCHUESA

[14875 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

Некоторые пояснения:

сначала надо преобразовать CSV значения в списки:

```
In [287]: df['System'].str.split(',\s*', expand=False)
Out[287]:
0        [P1B_010, P2Z_010]
1        [P1B_010, P2Z_010]
2        [P1B_010, P2Z_010]
3        [P3Z_020, P3Z_030]
4        [P1B_010, P2Z_010]
                ...
11695             [P1B_010]
11696             [P1B_010]
11697             [P1B_010]
11700             [P1B_010]
11701             [P3Z_020]
Name: System, Length: 11643, dtype: object
```

тоже самое с заменой столбца `System` в DF:

```
In [288]: df.assign(System=df['System'].str.split(',\s*', expand=False))
Out[288]:
         UserID              System          CONCAT A
0       ANTANAS  [P1B_010, P2Z_010]   P1B_010|ANTANAS
1       AWYGASC  [P1B_010, P2Z_010]   P1B_010|AWYGASC
2       CHENQIA  [P1B_010, P2Z_010]   P1B_010|CHENQIA
3       CHENQIA  [P3Z_020, P3Z_030]   P3Z_020|CHENQIA
4       DBORZUT  [P1B_010, P2Z_010]   P1B_010|DBORZUT
...         ...                 ...               ...
11695   TGUNZEN           [P1B_010]   P1B_010|TGUNZEN
11696  TSCHULTK           [P1B_010]  P1B_010|TSCHULTK
11697    WEHEIL           [P1B_010]    P1B_010|WEHEIL
11700   RSIELAF           [P1B_010]   P1B_010|RSIELAF
11701   SCHUESA           [P3Z_020]   P3Z_020|SCHUESA

[11643 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

Код функции `explode()`:

```
def explode(df, lst_cols, fill_value=''):
    # make sure `lst_cols` is a list
    if lst_cols and not isinstance(lst_cols, list):
        lst_cols = [lst_cols]
    # all columns except `lst_cols`
    idx_cols = df.columns.difference(lst_cols)

    # calculate lengths of lists
    lens = df[lst_cols[0]].str.len()

    if (lens > 0).all():
        # ALL lists in cells aren't empty
        return pd.DataFrame({
            col:np.repeat(df[col].values, lens)
            for col in idx_cols
        }).assign(**{col:np.concatenate(df[col].values) for col in lst_cols}) \
          .loc[:, df.columns]
    else:
        # at least one list in cells is empty
        return pd.DataFrame({
            col:np.repeat(df[col].values, lens)
            for col in idx_cols
        }).assign(**{col:np.concatenate(df[col].values) for col in lst_cols}) \
          .append(df.loc[lens==0, idx_cols]).fillna(fill_value) \
          .loc[:, df.columns]
```

Comment: Я не знаю что не так, потому что я не могу получить такой же рузельтат даже когда я просто исполняю указанный код. Появляется ошибка: `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64')` according to the rule 'safe', а если я конвертирую в функции len of list, с помощью `.fillna(value=0).astype(int)`, то появляется ошибка: `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

Comment: попробуйте привести в вопросе пример данных, с помощью которого можно воспроизвести данную ошибку...

Comment: @user21, возможно проблема вызвана пустыми строками в Excel. Попробуйте прочитать его так: `df = pd.read_excel(filename).dropna(how='all')`

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое, я удалил `NaN` и ошибок больше не появлялось, а код исполнялся корректно. `df2 = df.dropna(subset = ['UserID', 'System'])`